# Suitable audio player for website which works on android as well as iPad

Tags: jquery, jwplayer, audio-player

I have a website where I am embedding the flash player which does not work for android and iPad.

Then I have tried [`JW Player`](http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1406724-aac-or-mp3-audio-embed) which works on most of the platforms except `SAMSUNG Note 10 inch` so which audio player is suitable for audio which works on all the platforms?

Platforms: Andriod mobiles , ipad, tablet, iphone, note-pad, desktop browsers.

Comment: None. Supporting ALL platforms is impossible. Try to define 'all'.

Comment: What about the `<audio>` tag (not supported in IE8 and Opera mini) :D

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan But that may not work on older browsers?

Comment: @VishalSuthar only IE8 and below. You need IE8 support? A quick Goog will lead you to some suggestions / polyfills.

Comment: Also no <audio> tag in Firefox on WinXP or OSX (OK in WinVista, Win7/8).